# Item is not being remove from list

Tags: c#, wpf

Item is not being remove from list

here is my code:

```
public interface IEmpConnection
{
    int SegId { get; set; }
}

public class EmpConnection : IEmpConnection
{

    private int segid;
    public int SegId
    {
        get
        {
            return segid;
        }
        set
        {
            segid = value;
        }
    }
}

public class CustomerConnection : EmpConnection, ICustomerConnection
{

    private int _id;

    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
        }
    }
}

public interface ICustomerConnection
{
    int Id { get; set; }


}

public class CustConn : CustomerConnection
{
    private ObservableCollection<CustomerConnection> _airSeg;

    public CustConn()
    {
        _airSeg = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<CustomerConnection>();
        _airSeg.Add(new AirSegmentConnection { Id = 1, SegId = 2 });
        _airSeg.Add(new AirSegmentConnection { Id = 1, SegId = 3 });
    }

    private bool isDeleted;

    public bool IsDeleted
    {
        get { return isDeleted; }
        set { isDeleted = value; }
    }

    private List<IEmpConnection> _connection;
    public List<IEmpConnection> Connections
    {
        get
        {
            var s = new AirSegmentConnection();
            var k = s as ISegmentConnection;

            if (IsDeleted)
            {
                _airSeg.RemoveAt(1);
            }

            return _connection = _airSeg.ToList().Cast<ISegmentConnection>().ToList();
            //return _airSeg.ToList().Cast<ISegmentConnection>().ToList();
        }

        set
        {
            _connection = value;
            //_airSeg = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<ISegmentConnection>(value.ToList()) ;
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<CustomerConnection> airConnection;

    public ObservableCollection<CustomerConnection> AirConnection
    {
        get { return _airSeg; }
        set { _airSeg = value; }
    }
}
```

on main

button click item is not being removed. please suggest me where i am doing wrong.

```
CustConn a = new CustConn();
if (a.Connections.Count > 0)
{
    a.Connections = new List<IEmpConnection>();
    a.Connections.RemoveAt(1);// this item is not being removed.
}
```

please suggest i am doing worng in this code.

Thanks
Amit

Comment: Can you provide feedback on the answers suggested.  I noticed you posted this question again.  Did these answers not meet your needs?  What happened?

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new, empty list and then trying to remove an element at position 1. In fact you've just overwritten your original list.

```
if (a.Connections.Count > 0)
{
    /// REMOVE THIS LINE a.Connections = new List<IEmpConnection>();
    a.Connections.RemoveAt(1);// this item is not being removed.
}
```

The line I've commented out it creating a new list and **overwriting** `a.Connections` immediately before you try to remove the item. This is what's causing the code to fail.

Comment: i am putting two items into connection list but item no 1 is not being deleted return return 2 item. but why.

Comment: @Amit it's because you are **overwriting** `a.Connections` with the line I've commented out.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are replacing the list of connections before you remove the connection.

Since you have this marked as WPF, I'm going to assume that at some point you were able to remove the item from the List, but it still appeared on the screen.  Try this:

```
if (a.Connections.Count > 0)
{
     var newList = new List<IEmpConnection>(a.Connections);
     a.Connections.RemoveAt(1);
     a.Connections = newList;
}
```

Alternatively, you may be able to use an `ObservableCollection<IEmpConnection>`.  This is a special collection that raises events when the collection changes.  Then you would simple remove the object, and the screen would update.

Comment: it working var newList = new List<IEmpConnection>(a.Connections);      a.Connections.RemoveAt(1);      a.Connections = newList;

Comment: That is good to know.  Is there anything else you want help with before you accept an answer?

Comment: Connection is type of list so when item is deleted from list then i want send the notification list was modified to UI. but notifications has not been supported List.in this peice of code there is any way to send notification to UI after list was modified.

Comment: Can you use ObservableCollection<IEmpConnection> instead of a list?  This raises events when the collection changes

Comment: (ObservableCollection<IEmpConnection>) would be more specific for WPF or silverlight apps.